# How to get OAuthConsumerKey and OAuthConsumerSecret from Twitter for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

I'm developing an iOS app in which i want to tweet some text from my application.My doubt is

1. How to create(register) my app in twitter site? and
2. How to get OAuthConsumerKey and OAuthConsumerSecret from Twitter for my app?

Any links or references or docs or any help is thankful in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create(register) my app in twitter site?

Read the docs on http://dev.twitter.com

> How to get OAuthConsumerKey and OAuthConsumerSecret from Twitter for
>   my app?

You have to use some kind of Objective-C OAuth library to handle this for you. Consider using the overly popular [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) or my modified [OAuth Library](http://github.com/H2CO3/MPOAuthiOS)